# What encoding to use for categorical data where distinct values might be over a million

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

My use case for machine learning is to classify whether the gender is male(1) or female(2) based on two features, Name and Nationality. The total number of records are 80 million. Samples look like:

```
Name    Nationality Gender
John    201           1
Sue     401           2
Smith   401           1
.... Millions of rows (but to start I'm just picking 10K records)
```

As I understand that the categorical data has to be encoded. I've gone through a number of examples and I can see that the distinct values in those example are reasonable whereas in my use case the distinct values can be even 1 million. I started out small just using around 10K of samples and implemented labelEncoder and different algorithms. Not getting good accuracy at all. The best is 0.78 from the decisionTreeClassifier. New to machine learning, I have the following questions:

1. I think only Name is needed to be encoded. What do you think?
2. What encoder(s) to use in this case, considering there might be
   hundreds of thousands distinct values?
3. What algorithm(s) do you think will work better for this kind of
   problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try work more on feature exploration, for example n-gams might be useful 
That may help you with unknown examples

Just a name is not going to help you much, it's just memory